# Session.getActiveUser.getEmail() blank? Google sheets

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I want to check the user who is clicking that specific button. When I click on while signed in as my account it runs fine.
but if anyone else runs it, it is blank. How can I get the logged user email id?

This is my code:

```
function check_User(){
  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  var usr = Session.getActiveUser().getEmail();
  ss.toast(usr);
  if( usr == "abc@gmail.com" || usr =="myemail@gmail.com"){ 

    return true;
  }
  else{
    ui.alert("Not authorized");
    return false;
   }
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

See [getActiveUser()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/base/session#getActiveUser()) method description:

> If security policies do not allow access to the user's identity,
>   `User.getEmail()` returns a blank string. The circumstances in which the
>   email address is available vary: for example, the user's email address
>   is not available in any context that allows a script to run without
>   that user's authorization, like a simple onOpen(e) or onEdit(e)
>   trigger, a custom function in Google Sheets, or a web app deployed to
>   "execute as me" (that is, authorized by the developer instead of the
>   user). However, these restrictions generally do not apply if the
>   developer and the user belong to the same Google Apps for Business
>   domain.

What *execute* permission is your app deployed with? If it is *"as you (owner)"*, then `getActiveUser().getEmail()` will only be populated if you (script owner) and the users belong to the same Google Apps domain.

Judging from your code, you are not using Google Apps domain account, but a regular consumer @gmail.com account to publish your script. In this case `getActiveUser().getEmail()` will only be populated if your script is published with *execute as user accessing the script* permission.

Comment: You need to deploy your app and user must be access on your application.

Comment: This doesn't seem to work for me; I've deployed my app, it's set to execute as "User accessing the web app", and it still doesn't populate even when running as myself or anyone else on my domain.