# Edit History in Google Sheet

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

This code updates only the Last edit of the cell (User, Date & Time) and inserts as Note OnEdit

```
function onEdit(e) {
 var email = Session.getActiveUser().getEmail();
  var curDate = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), "GMT+05:30", "EEEE dd-MMM-yyyy ● hh:mm a")
  if (e.range.columnStart === 5 && e.source.getActiveSheet().getName() == 'ARTWORK') {// Column 12 is Column L
    //Set a comment on the edited cell to indicate when it was changed.
    e.range.setNote('Updated by - ' +email+ '\n\nDate & Time\n' + curDate);
  };
}
```

But my requirement is, can we add a history of edit in the cell as a Note?

e.g.
EDITED by NYK at 11-Sep-2020 - 11:20 am
EDITED by XYZ at 12-Sep-2020 - 12:20 pm
EDITED by ABC at 15-Sep-2020 - 15:01 pm

Is this possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Explanation:

- You can get the current notes of the cell and append a new note when
  an edit is made to this particular cell.
- To accomplish this task, you can use [getNote()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getnote) to get the
  current notes of the selected cell and then use [setNote()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setnotenote) to
  update the notes by adding the additional note to the existing ones:

  ```
  var current_notes = e.range.getNote();
  e.range.setNote(`${current_notes}\n\n Updated by -  ${email} \nDate & Time\n  ${curDate}`);
  ```
- Since the latter string expression involves a lot of variables, it
  is preferable to use [Template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) instead.

---

### Solution:

```
function onEdit(e) {
 var email = Session.getActiveUser().getEmail();
  var curDate = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), "GMT+05:30", "EEEE dd-MMM-yyyy ● hh:mm a")
  if (e.range.columnStart === 5 && e.source.getActiveSheet().getName() == 'ARTWORK' && e.range.getValue() !="") {// Column 12 is Column L
    var current_notes = e.range.getNote();
    e.range.setNote(`${current_notes}\n\n Updated by -  ${email} \nDate & Time\n  ${curDate}`);  
    SpreadsheetApp.flush();
  };
}
```

---

### Illustration:

[image: example]

---

### Relevant information:

Edit history of a cell is a new feature recently introduced by google. As of now there is no way to use Google Apps Script to get    the edit history of a cell. This feature has been already reported    for implementation in the [IssueTracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/144151809). You can click on the    star button on the left top corner of the screen to increase the    chances that this feature will be implemented in the future by google.

Comment: It's almost done but at first edit, it's setting 2 notes (in first note the user isn't mentioned) and in second edit it's adding 2 more notes and it keeps repeating, this may confuse the viewers and hard to understand what's going on. Is there any way to fix this?

Comment: @MuhammedAadhil hmm I am not sure if I understand. You want a history of the edits in s cell. That means you keep the old note and you add on top of that. So every time the edits the cell, the update of the edit will be saved as a note on top of the current notes in the cell. Can you clarify please more ?

Comment: @MuhammedAadhil or you mean you want to clear the note just in the first run of the script ? Namely, clear the notes that you have in your sheet right now . Is this what you want ?

Comment: I'm supposed to get 1 note for 1 edit and 2 notes for 2 edits and 3 notes for 3 edits, but I'm getting 2 notes for a 1 edit and sometimes its with duplicate timestamp.

Comment: I think you are getting that because the notes of the cell will be updated every time you **edit** the cell. That includes **deleting** the content of the cell or **replacing** it directly with another value. Do you want the notes to be updated only when the cell is updated with another (non blank) value? Let me know and I will modify the code. @MuhammedAadhil

Comment: I didn't understand what you meant by (non blank) Value. Sorry for lack of coding knowledge :(. I only need is, I want to know who edited and at what time it occurred. That's all.

Comment: You don't need to know code to understand this. I just ask you if when a person deletes the content of a cell, do you also want to capture that change? For example if you click on a cell and press the delete button on your keyboard. The value of the cell will disappear right? do you want to capture that change and add a note of that change? @MuhammedAadhil

Comment: Sorry @Marios for my lack of understanding, your last comment made it clear, If I delete the content, it's not necessary to add a note but only if it has a value in it.

Comment: @Moris I'm getting 5 notes for 3 edits (some don't contain the username in it.

Comment: @MuhammedAadhil if you see the gif picture in my answer, I edited the cell 3 times with a non blank value and I got 3 notes. How is it possible that you get more notes?

Comment: @MuhammedAadhil also regarding the empty users, check this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28474704/session-getactiveuser-getemail-blank-google-sheets .

Comment: See also the official documentation: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/base/session

Comment: @moris, I tried many times but i'm getting more notes than the edits and I'm the only user editing it but I'm not getting the user name in some notes.

Comment: Like I said, see the gif, that is my situation. I can't confirm your situation because I **can not** reproduce it. If you also provide a gif, then I can see that is indeed wrong and maybe I can fix it. But right now, I can't understand why it does not work for you.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/221682/discussion-between-muhammed-aadhil-and-marios).